# C++ Reverse char array by pairs

Tags: c++, hex, reverse

How do I reverse a hex number (char array) by pairs. I have A1B1C1 and i want to reverse it into C1B1A1. I have been trying to figure it out for a couple days but I dont see anywhere where anyone deals with pairs.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: Any rules? There are many ways to do this...you can use strings and string pointers, you can use old fashion char*, you can use boost libraries, etc.

Comment: If you were lazy like me you could do it in two passes. First reverse the entire string and then reverse each letter pair in a second pass. It's simple and therefore easy to get correct.

Comment: I am quite lazy. I tried to copy every other pair to its own buffer and then putting it back together but that caused something to break (what I know not) I have tried alot but not running it threw another pass

Answer (score 3):

I just pooped out this code based on my comment above. It seems to work in my brief testing.

The idea is simple, an initial pass to reverse the entire character string and a second pass to swap adjacent letter pairs.

```
void reverse_by_pairs(std::string &s)
{
    if (s.size() & 1) return; // reject odd-length strings

    std::reverse(begin(s), end(s));

    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < s.size(); i += 2) {
        std::swap(s[i], s[i + 1]);
    }
}
```

And after a little modification you can reverse pairs of arbitrary types:

```
template <typename T>
void reverse_by_pairs(T *seq, size_t size)
{
    if (size & 1) return; // reject odd-length sequence

    std::reverse(seq, seq + size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i + 1 < size; i += 2) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(seq[i], seq[i + 1]);
    }
}

void reverse_by_pairs(std::string &s)
{
    if (s.size() > 1) {
        reverse_by_pairs(&s[0], s.size());
    }
}

void reverse_by_pairs(char *s)
{
    reverse_by_pairs(s, strlen(s));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wanted an array of characters, I have done the following:

**1)** assumed that the string is A1B2C3

**2)** you are using an old compiler as in new compilers the `std::string` class can be used instead of making an array of characters.

The code goes something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio>
void main() {
   char a[] = "A1B2C3";
   int n = 6;
   for (int y = 0; y<n ; y++) {
        for (int x = 0 ; a[x]<a[x+2] ; x++) {
            char t = a[x];
            a[x] = a[x+2];
            a[x+2]=t;
        }
   }
   cout<<a;
   getch();
}
```

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ lol no idea , let me edit it